# How to pull Teamviewer connected users or Id's in C#

Tags: c#, teamviewer

How can I pull a list of current users connected via Teamviewer to a computer.

I understand that the Teamviewer Connections_incommint.txt populates with this info however, it's only after the connection is terminated.

Use case: Our support team often runs a few in-house tools @ various client locations. During execution of the tool I would like to determine which team member ran the tool (is connected via Teamviewer) to forward relevant logs to them. Pulling this info from Teamviewer and filtering off a short-list of our 20ish team members would avoid the use of logins etc on the tools and automate the attribution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What did you try?

Comment: Hey Jeroen, great question!
I've searched through the Teamviewer API and saw no reference:
https://dl.tvcdn.de/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf

I've also searched through the registry while connected for my TV ID with no luck.